# showing $x^4+x^2+x+1$ is reducible in $GF(81)=GF(3^4)$

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

I am trying to show that in $GF(81)=GF(3^4)$,

$$x^4+x^2+x+1$$ is reducible

I proved that it was irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_3$

How can I prove this  ?

More generally, how to prove if a polynomial is /  is not reducible in finite fields ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}_3$?

Comment: yes this is what I mean !

Comment: $\mathbb{F}_{3^\color{red}4}$ is the splitting field of $x^\color{red}4+x^2+x+1\in \mathbb{F}_{3}[x]$ .

Comment: @RiccardoAllegrone How do you know

Comment: If $f(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_q[x]$, then its splitting field is given by $\mathbb{F}_{q^{\deg(f)}}$ (it's a theorem).

Comment: @RiccardoAllegrone i'm too tired to even have seen it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that $f(x)=x^4+x^2+x+1$ has a linear factor if and only if $f(x)$ has a root in $\mathbb{F}_3$. We see $f(0),f(1),f(2) \not = 0$ so $f(x)$ has no linear factor.

Then if it is reducible it must have quadratic factors that are irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_3$. 
$$x^4+x^2+x+1 = (ax^2+bx+c)(dx^2+ex+f)$$
$$x^4+x^2+x+1 = adx^4+(ae+bd)x^3+(af+cd)x^2+(bf+ce)x+cf$$
See if you can solve from there.

Comment: We have to identify and solve a system, okay I've got the idea thanks !

Comment: How do you prove there is a root in $GF(81)$ though ?

Comment: If $f(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_3[x]$, then $\mathbb{F}_3[x]/(f(x)) \cong $GF$(81)$, like the commenter above said.

Comment: Oh, I am too tired to do math, how can I be so blind...